# CKEditor is not editable when opened second time on popup in chrome

Tags: jquery, fancybox, ckeditor, colorbox

When i open a CKEditor in a popup(colorbox or fancybox), it works fine for the first time.

When the popup is closed and opened for the second time, the content area is not clickable/editable and its not displaying the content.

But the Content shows when i click "Source" button and then its available on design view. This is fine in IE and Firefox, but issue is with CHROME.

I have followed what is said in [CKEditor loading in Colorbox not working [ Google Chrome ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162988/ckeditor-loading-in-colorbox-not-working-google-chrome), but still i have this issue.

Below is the sample Code what i have in my application:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>CKEditor Sample</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ckeditor.com/apps/ckeditor/3.6.2/ckeditor.js?1324772165"></script>

    <link href="http://fancybox.net/js/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://fancybox.net/js/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {
            if (CKEDITOR.instances['taCKEditor']) {
                delete CKEDITOR.instances['taCKEditor'];
            }
            CKEDITOR.config.height = '500px';
            CKEDITOR.config.width = '500px';
            CKEDITOR.config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
            CKEDITOR.config.shiftEnterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_P;
            CKEDITOR.config.startupFocus = true;
            CKEDITOR.config.baseFloatZIndex = 9000;
            CKEDITOR.replace('taCKEditor',
        {
            uiColor: '#fdd1ad',
            toolbar:
            [
                ['Source', '-', 'NewPage', 'Preview'],
                ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', '-', 'Print', 'SpellChecker'],
                ['Undo', 'Redo', '-', 'Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', 'RemoveFormat'],
                '/',
                ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', '-', 'Subscript', 'Superscript'],
                ['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'],
                ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor'],
                ['Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak'],
                '/',
                ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize'],
                ['TextColor', 'BGColor']
            ]
        });

            $("#various1").fancybox({
                'titlePosition': 'inside',
                'transitionIn': 'none',
                'transitionOut': 'none'
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <a id="various1" href="#inline1" ">Open CKEditor</a>
    <div id="inline1">
        <textarea id="taCKEditor" name="taCKEditor" rows="2" cols="5">This is the sample text inside CKEditor</textarea>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A link will be helpful to see the issue

Comment: @JFK, i have included the sample with the question.

Comment: Did anyone get a solution for this? Still there's issue with the CHROME.

Comment: this helps:

after replace() make 

CKEDITOR.instances["ckeditor"].setData( CKEDITOR.instances["ckeditor"].getData );

Answer (score 0):

You need to create form and inside form insert textarea. Assign fancybox to form id. In javascript trigger click for form. In fancybox callback beforeLoad use CKEditor loader that will check if instance exists and if not then it will remove it. In beforeLoad load to ckeditor content from html block.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've encountered the same problem before. Have you tried the `CKEDITOR.replace()`. For example:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('taCKEditor');
```

Then after that do the `CKEDITOR.instance`.

Or don't you think the `delete` cause the problem. Anyway, I just assume.